# I want to find the time-displacement curve through inverse fast Fourier transform

Tags: python, numpy, fft

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=1000; T=10; dt=T/N
t=np.arange(0,N*dt,dt)

#system properties
wn = 4 * np.pi
w=0.2*wn
Tn = 2*np.pi/wn
fn = 1/Tn

m = 1
Z = 0.05
k = wn*wn * m
c = 2*m*wn*Z
######################################################
P = np.sin(wn * t)

#Frequency response
L = len(P)
a = np.arange(L)
freq = a * (1/dt) / L
freq = freq[range(int(L/2))]

Pf = np.fft.fft(P)/L
Pf = Pf[range(int(L/2))]
FFT = 2*abs(Pf)
#########################################################
# transfer function
H=(1/k)*(1/(1+(w/wn)**2)+1j*(2*Z*(w/wn)))

Uf=2*Pf*H

# for i in range(0,int(N/2)):
#     Uf[N-i-1] = np.conjugate(Uf[i+1])

ut= np.real(np.fft.ifft(Uf)*(1/dt))

plt.plot(t, ut)
plt.show()
```

i don't know this ValueError
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (500,)
I want to find the time-displacement curve through inverse fast Fourier transform

Answer (score 0):

The `plt.plot()` function is just complaining that `t` and `ut` do not have the same length.

This line `Pf = Pf[range(int(L/2))]` takes `Pf` from an array of length `N` to `N/2`. This affects `Uf` and consequently `ut`, and that is why you get the error message. Im not sure what you are trying to do in this command... are you trying to filter out certain frequencies? Either way, taking another look at this command might give you what you want.